# Expo Push Notification for iOS APNS

Tags: ios, react-native, push-notification

I have a `React Native` App for `Android/iOS.` I've already tested the android push notification with firebase and expo. **Do I still need to configure APNS for the push notification for iOS or it will work?** currently i have no iOS Device to test it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you would need to configure APNS for push notification. You can't even test iOS notification in virtual machine or a simulator. Notifications can be tested only in a physical iOS devices.

Comment: I'm banging my head for 1 week now. Thanks. Do you any resources to configure apns in sdk 37 of expo?